# Qualcomm Atheros AR9285 gets down frequently in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, wireless

I see my Wifi stops and gets disconnected frequently, and have to restart again to get it work.Its serious problem as its affecting my work.

```
aman@hellbox:~$ lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net
03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 05)
        Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:3975]
        Kernel driver in use: r8169
04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) [168c:002b] (rev 01)
        Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:31a1]
        Kernel driver in use: ath9k
```

Comment: What wifi card is it?  Please edit question to include the results from `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net`

Comment: aman@hellbox:~$ lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net
03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 05)
 Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:3975]
 Kernel driver in use: r8169
04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) [168c:002b] (rev 01)
 Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:31a1]
 Kernel driver in use: ath9k

Comment: Do you have any control over the wifi access point, or is it a work network?

Comment: i can control the wifi, its for personal use.

Comment: Please use the [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/596629/edit) to add information to your question. Lengthy terminal output is hard to read in the comment section.

Answer (score 0):

add this option in kernel drivers settings

```
$ sudo echo 'options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1' >> /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
```

Then restart the system this must fix wifi problem.

Comment: i am getting an error:      bash: /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf: Permission denied

Comment: I don't know anything about this configuration file. But the proper way to do this on the command line would be `$ echo 'options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1' | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf`, as seen on http://superuser.com/a/136653

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do that helps people with Atheros wifi cards is to use WPA2 encryption only.  If you run `iwlist scan` and find your wifi network you want to see CCMP after group cipher and pairwise cipher, no TKIP

Comment: I found this output :::
aman@hellbox:~$ iwlist scan
             
                    IE: Unknown: 7F0101
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: Unknown:

Comment: how can i change the settings you mentioned

Comment: You will have to login to your router to change the settings for most you type the routers IP address into a browser.  For my router I can access using the IP Address under gateway from command `route -n` You might want to look at the owners manual for details.